# do i need to format the URL differently?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using an ajax request in my javascript:

```
 xmlHttpReq.open("GET", "/root/handlerfolder/SomeHandler.ashx?id="+id)
```

Just wondering if I have to use some url helper in case I am moving this to a production or other environment ie different server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `ResolveUrl`

```
xmlHttpReq.open("GET", '<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/root/handlerfolder/SomeHandler.ashx")%>?id='+id);
```